# Use User-Agent C# for divices Android and iOS

Tags: c#, user-agent

I have two buttons one to download .apk and another to download .ipa, in HomeController i have:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public FileResult DownloadiOS()
    {
       var fileName = ("app.ipa");
       var filepath = $"Apps/{fileName}";
       byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);
       return File(fileBytes, "application/ipa", fileName);  
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public FileResult DownloadAndroid()
    {
        var fileName = ("app.apk");
        var filepath = $"Apps/{fileName}";
        byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);
        return File(fileBytes, "application/apk", fileName);
    }
```

What I want to do is that I can not download from an Android Device the iOS app and vice versa. Use a User-Agent example:

```
    if (userAgent.Contains("Android"))
    {
        clientOsName = GetOsVersion(userAgent, "Android");
        ....
    }

    else (userAgent.Contains("iPhone"))
    {
        clientOsName = GetOsVersion(userAgent, "iPhone");
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Sounds like a plan. What's your question?

Comment: Yeah what are you even asking?

Comment: What I want to do is that I can not download from an Android Device the iOS app and vice versa.?

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do.  Please read how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Noooo shit? So are you asking HOW to check the devicetype?

Comment: Yes, I just want the iPhone to download .ipa and Android only .apk